# how can i get the mouse click position from my JMapViewer world map

Tags: java, gps, jmapviewer, world-map

Im using the [JMapViewer](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer) jar to show the world map on a JPanel.

On the map im adding `MapMarkerDot's` which are gps points.

The problem is when i click a `MapMarkerDot` on the map i cannot
find an interface or listener to catch the click and give me the
clicked `MapMarkerDot` identity.

has anyone here worked with the code or can give me some ideas what to do.

I would not like to modify the jar source but maybe i have to input an interface.

I know this is kind of an abstract question but hoping for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.
Basically solved this by raw x/y calculation comparing the
MapMarker position against mouse click position.

```
if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
    Point p = e.getPoint();
    int X = p.x+3;
    int Y = p.y+3;
    List<MapMarker> ar = map.getMapMarkerList();
    Iterator<MapMarker> i = ar.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {

        MyMapMarkerDot mapMarker = (MyMapMarkerDot) i.next();

        if(mapMarker.position != null){

            int centerX =  mapMarker.position.x;
            int centerY = mapMarker.position.y;

            // calculate the radius from the touch to the center of the dot
            double radCircle  = Math.sqrt( (((centerX-X)*(centerX-X)) + (centerY-Y)*(centerY-Y)));

            // if the radius is smaller then 23 (radius of a ball is 5), then it must be on the dot
            if (radCircle < 8){
                ShowClickedUser(mapMarker.Tag);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the code of DefaultMapController.java :

```
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    if(e.getClickCount() == 1 && e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){

         Point p = e.getPoint();
            int X = p.x+3;
            int Y = p.y+3;
            List<MapMarker> ar = map.getMapMarkerList();
            Iterator<MapMarker> i = ar.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {

                MapMarker mapMarker = (MapMarker) i.next();

                Point MarkerPosition = map.getMapPosition(mapMarker.getLat(), mapMarker.getLon());
                if( MarkerPosition != null){

                    int centerX =  MarkerPosition.x;
                    int centerY = MarkerPosition.y;

                    // calculate the radius from the touch to the center of the dot
                    double radCircle  = Math.sqrt( (((centerX-X)*(centerX-X)) + (centerY-Y)*(centerY-Y)));

                    // if the radius is smaller then 23 (radius of a ball is 5), then it must be on the dot
                    if (radCircle < 8){
                        System.out.println(mapMarker.toString() + " is clicked");                       }

                }
            }
    }

    else if (doubleClickZoomEnabled && e.getClickCount() == 2 && e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        map.zoomIn(e.getPoint());
    }
}
```

Hope this will help! Welcome to further discussion.