# Map with pie chart and label

Tags: google-maps, charts, chart.js, jfreechart, pie-chart

I've been looking for map charts with pie charts on them where tooltip will pop on hover having the data in it. Now, I've been looking for some libraries like http://jvectormap.com, amcharts that have this functionality. But I have no interest in buying these products since all I want to use is this module.

I tried Google map with chart maker but still not getting what I actually want.

Here is a screenshot of what I want to create:

[image]

I would appreciate if someone could help me. Meanwhile, I will continue my research on them

Answer (score 1):

Using [jmapviewer](/questions/tagged/jmapviewer), add a custom `MapMarker`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33857113/230513). In your marker's implementation of `paint()`, invoke the `draw()` method of the `JFreeChart` matching the marker's coordinates. A typical invocation is seen in the [`paintComponent()`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.java#L1293) method of `ChartPanel`.